# "Why so sudden?" or "why so suddenly?"

Tags: grammar, questions

> Why did Mary quit her job? Why so sudden?
>
> Why did Mary quit her job? Why so suddenly?

What's the correct option? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the second one would be "more correct," because you want an adverb to modify the verb *quit*.

Informally, either one will work. The word *sudden* can be used as an adverb to mean *suddenly*; check out the word's entry in NOAD:

[image]

Your question hasn't given any background information or context. Is this a conversation by the office water cooler? If so, **informal language is entirely appropriate, so either one could be used**. Is this part of an exposé published in a respected newspaper? In that case, the editor might recommend the second one (presumably, journalists would be held to a higher standard, and should use the more "pure" adverbial form).